# how can i get the row index when i click linkbutton in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to target when i clik the link button get the index of row. However, Icannot get it.

My c# codes:

```
 int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

when the codes comes here gives error({"Input string was not in a correct format."}) however, it works for example when i click buttonfield.  how can i do it?

asp.net codes

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="View"><%#Eval("RSS_Title") %></asp:LinkButton>
           </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="YourGrid" 
              OnRowCommand="YourGrid_RowCommand"
              OnRowCreated="YourGrid_RowCreated"  
              runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="View">
           <%#Eval("RSS_Title") %></asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CS**

```
protected void YourGrid_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="View")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
protected void YourGrid_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      var LinkButton2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
      LinkButton2.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: @sarvar206 answer will just work for the first row. If you have 10 rows the row index will still be 1. Which will result in you picking values from the same row all the time. If that is what you want then do that. Else my answer will get you the target row in the rowcommand

Comment: yes, it's just assumes a static value. If dynamic value needed, then it's value need to set from code behind or with Eval command. Thanks

Comment: That is what I was trying to say for the past 1 hour.. Glad to help you:P

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="View" CommandArgument="1"><%#Eval("RSS_Title") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

I mean, add a CommandArgument.